# LAMP server refuses connections from domain (accepts from IP)

Tags: apache, dns, lamp

I setup a apache server with LAMP, and I don't have any virtual hosts setup. If I visit it from a domain that has an A record pointing to the server ip and I try to visit it it shows me "The server refused to connect" and if I type in the IP directly into my browser it will show up with no problems. The firewall is open and on the access logs I can see myself connecting. There is a virtual host setup and here is the conf for it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@rewardsonline.io
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName rewardsonline.io
        ServerAlias www.rewardsonline.io
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

There is an A record pointing to the server IP on cloudflare with proxy on.

Comment: You must add virtual hosts so Apache understand how to handle the incoming request, otherwise it will refuse the connection

Comment: Yes, I have a virtual host setup for the domain but it doesn't work